# Make a cookie expire in 30 seconds

Tags: javascript, cookies

Could someone update the following code to make the cookie expire in 30 seconds.

```
function setCookie(c_name, value, exdays) {
    var exdate = new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;
}
```

Comment: So... you've done a copy/paste off w3schools... Quirksmode has a better explanation of cookies in JavaScript: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Why do you want it to expire so quickly?

Comment: @Jason There might be times when you simply want to pass data between pages without sending that information over the wire. In cases like that a quickly expiring cookie does a good job.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
function createCookie(name, value) {
   var date = new Date();
   date.setTime(date.getTime()+(30*1000));
   var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();

   document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}
```

Comment: Why we are using toGMTString() in expires? Is there any specific reason?

Answer (score 9):

You can specify the maximum age in seconds when setting a cookie:

```
function setCookie(name, value, maxAgeSeconds) {
    var maxAgeSegment = "; max-age=" + maxAgeSeconds;
    document.cookie = encodeURI(name) + "=" + encodeURI(value) + maxAgeSegment;
}
```

Usage:

```
setCookie("username", "blaise", 30);
```