# Save name and then say "hi" + name every session

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am trying to create a webpage that has an alert when you start it. User will get prompted to enter name or your username. The username will get saved in a cookie. **Everytime** a new session gets started user will see a message saying ***"hello" + username***. However, I haven't been able to do it without getting the message to popup after visiting a new part of the webpage.

This is my code so far:

### HTML

```
function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
        {
        var exdate=new Date();
        exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
        var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
        document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
        }

    function getCookie(c_name)
    {
        var c_value = document.cookie;
        var c_start = c_value.indexOf(" " + c_name + "=");
        if (c_start == -1)
          {
          c_start = c_value.indexOf(c_name + "=");
          }
        if (c_start == -1)
          {
          c_value = null;
          }
        else
          {
          c_start = c_value.indexOf("=", c_start) + 1;
          var c_end = c_value.indexOf(";", c_start);
          if (c_end == -1)
          {
        c_end = c_value.length;
        }
        c_value = unescape(c_value.substring(c_start,c_end));
        }
        window.c_value = c_value
    return c_value;
    }

    function alertornot(){
        if (get_cookie('alerted')==''){
        loadalert()
        document.cookie="alerted=yes"
        }
    }

    function loadalert(){
        alert(window.username + "we meet again" )
    }
    function alert() {
        var username=getCookie("username");
        

        if (username!=null && username!="") {


            if (once_per_session==0) {
                loadalert()
            }
            else {
                alertornot()
            }
        }
        else {
            username=prompt("Please enter your name:","");
            // window.username = username
            if (username!=null && username!="") {
                setCookies("username", username, 365)
            }

        }

    }
```

I'm very new to programming and javascript. I am so sorry, if this is a stupid question.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! There's no need to add tags to your title, there's a tag system for that. Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/147072 for more information.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp
It might help.
A good habit to get is to include a www.jsfiddle.net link to your question, thus letting other people fork with your code easily and fixing the issue faster.

Is there any of these functions called on `document.load()` ? Otherwise the Javascript won't be executed on pageload.
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp

Comment: It would be great when you ask questions if you could explain what you expect to happen using your code, and what actually happens. Sure, everyone can read and deduce it themselves, but slapping a wall of code and expecting everyone to read it is not the way to go around here. If you are using a [sscce](http://sscce.org) don't forget to format your code appropriately using correct indentation and avoid empty lines where they're not needed. You have a preview of the question, use it.

Answer (score 1):

1. You write "setCookies(...)", but it's "setCookie" without "s".
2. You make infinite loop, because you replace "alert(...)" native function and call alert() in this function.
   Execute schema : alert() > loadalert() > alert() > loadalert() > etc...

   Rename your function.
3. You didn't define "once_per_session" variable.

### Javascript

```
function n_alert() {
    window.username = getCookie("username");
    console.log(username);
    if (username!="undefined" && username!==null && username!=="") {
        alert(window.username + " we meet again" );
    } else {
        username=prompt("Please enter your name:","");

        if (username!==null && username!=="") {
            setCookie("username", username, 365);
        }
    }  
}

n_alert();
```

http://jsbin.com/ucipom/2/edit

Comment: The popup still comes when I refresh the page

Comment: @user2449116 See my new answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should not name a function `alert` as it is a global object already. Also, I do not see where you are calling any of this code.

I would rename the `alert` function to `promptUser` (or something) and add this code to the bottom:

```
promptUser();
loadAlert();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
function getCookie(c_name)
{
var c_value = document.cookie;
var c_start = c_value.indexOf(" " + c_name + "=");
if (c_start == -1)
{
c_start = c_value.indexOf(c_name + "=");
}
if (c_start == -1)
{
c_value = null;
}
else
{
c_start = c_value.indexOf("=", c_start) + 1;
var c_end = c_value.indexOf(";", c_start);
if (c_end == -1)
{
c_end = c_value.length;
}
c_value = unescape(c_value.substring(c_start,c_end));
}
return c_value;
}

function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
var exdate=new Date();
exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function checkCookie()
{
var username=getCookie("username");
if (username!=null && username!="")
  {
  alert("Welcome again " + username);
  }
else 
  {
  username=prompt("Please enter your name:","");
  if (username!=null && username!="")
    {
    setCookie("username",username,365);
    }
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="checkCookie()">
```

Comment: This was the first thing I tried, but as I said the hello message pops up everytime I refresh or go to a new page, Thanks for your time thou.

Answer (score 0):

My last [anwser here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16904413/2226755).

> The popup still comes when I refresh the page

If you want pop-up only one time (not each refresh page), set one other cookie.

See [Make a cookie expire in 30 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7879810/make-a-cookie-expire-in-30-seconds) for set Cookie with second and not with day (for popupcookie).

### Javascript

```
function isCookie(c_name) {
    var cook = getCookie(c_name);
    return (cook!="undefined" && cook!==null && cook!=="");
}

function n_alert() {
    var username = getCookie("username");
    if (isCookie("username")) {
        if (!isCookie("popupcookie")) {
            alert(username + " we meet again" );
        } else {
            console.log("hidden alert : " + username + " we meet again" );
        }
        setCookie("popupcookie", username, 1); //restart
    } else {
        username=prompt("Please enter your name:","");

        if (username!==null && username!=="") {
            setCookie("username", username, 365);
        }
    }
}

n_alert();
```

http://jsbin.com/ucipom/6/edit

Remark I found issue, if you use different directory (path) ex : '**./**' and '**./dir1/1/**'. You may have a problem. Like you don't define or re-define root cookie in directory. Maybe use [sessionstorage](http://code.google.com/p/sessionstorage/).