# Why we multiply seconds with 1000 in Javascript to add time

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am working on cookies and I found some questions on Stack Overflow which have been answered. I see in the questions that the answers multiplied seconds by 1000. I want know what format getTime() returns, that would require multiplying by 1000.

[Make a cookie expire in 30 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7879810/make-a-cookie-expire-in-30-seconds)

[How to set a cookie to expire in 1 hour in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794989/how-to-set-a-cookie-to-expire-in-1-hour-in-javascript)

Comment: Because JavaScript works with time in milliseconds, not seconds.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

JavaScript uses **milliseconds** to represent epoch time.

[Epoch time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_epoch) is the number of seconds since 01/01/1970 and there are [1000 milliseconds in one second](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond). So to get the number of milliseconds since 01/01/1970 you just multiply the value by 1000.

Reference -

- [MDN - Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: <sarcasm>Since, of course, the world was created in whole in the last second of 1969.</sarcasm>

Comment: Well it had to start *somewhere*! ;)

Comment: well answered. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Because it's given to you in milliseconds.

```
Seconds * 1000 = Milliseconds
```

Comment: Seconds * 1000 = Milliseconds

Answer (score 2):

[getTime](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime)

> The value returned by the getTime method is the number of milliseconds
>   since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC

Answer (score 1):

It's using milliseconds. That's why we need to multiply the seconds with 1000 to get an equivalent value.